# Simple char output from string

Tags: c

I am learning C and I simply wanted to output the first char of the string that the user inputs. Somehow it doesnt work? I also got no error message. This must be a really simple question, but I dont get it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char input[200];
    char test;
    printf("Text input: ");
    scanf("%s", input);
    test = input[0];
    printf("%s", test);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf("%s", test);` should be `%c` - you can't mix up control string like that.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! But it still doesn't work. Program still won't do anything.

Comment: Try adding `fflush(stdin);` before scanf statement. @Valakor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `%c` to print a `char`. `%s` is for null-terminated strings, i.e. char arrays. The code below works fine for me.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char input[200];
    char test;
    printf("Text input: ");
    scanf("%s", input);
    test = input[0];
    printf("%c\n", test);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
char input[200];
char test;
printf("Text input: ");
scanf("%s", input);
test = input[0];
printf("%c\n", test);
return 0;
}
```

This works. U need to use `%c` rather than `%s` to print characters